# Wordpress: Can these 2 functions be combined into one?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to combine/refactor (if possible) these 2 functions into 1 since their scope is narrowly focused to one tax on my site. Purpose is to redirect links to a taxonomy term to the first (oldest) post in that category in the most efficient way possible:

```
function redirect_series() {
  if (is_tax('series')) {
    global $post;
        wp_safe_redirect(get_permalink($post->ID));
    die;
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect','redirect_series');

function order_by_date_callback ( $query ) {
    if (($query->is_main_query()) && (is_tax('series'))) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'order_by_date_callback' );
```

Comment: No, you can't. The first function is run after a post is fetched as the global $post. The second function runs as a pre_get_posts hook that runs before any post is fetched from the database. They are run in different part of the Wordpress lifecycle and hence cannot be written as one function.

Comment: Ok, thank you for taking the time to reply. I appreciate it